# SQLAlchemy table with 2 primary_keys how to autoincrement the first primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have table with 2 primary keys, where second primary key is also a foreign key. When I try to populate the DB I will get "NOT NULL constraint failed: items.id1" error. When populating I will always provide known id for id2. So how can I make the sqlalchemy to autoincrement id1?

```
class items(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id1 = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True).with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True,)
    #location id
    id2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table2.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Combination of id1 and id2 has to always be unique, and combination of those 2 are used to identify the items. id1 isn't enough since databases can be in several locations and tables are synchronized time to time.

I already tried this solution but it's outdated and doesn't work anymore: [How to insert a row with autoincrement id in a multi-primary-key table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372525/how-to-insert-a-row-with-autoincrement-id-in-a-multi-primary-key-table?rq=1)

EDIT:
Work around for this problem is to use Postgres DB. SQLite is lite but dumb.

Comment: Try this autoincrement=True

Comment: Nothing, same error.

Comment: Another option is to use uuids instead of 2 primary keys.  That way you always know that your id is unique:  `from uuid import uuid4;  id = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid4())`.  At this point you can drop the primary key on the foreign key as it's no longer necessary as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlite:

```
id1 = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True).with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True, sqlite_autoincrement=True)
id2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table2.id'), primary_key=True, sqlite_autoincrement=False)
```

If you are using mysql, then simple autoincrement will work:

```
id1 = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True).with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
id2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table2.id'), primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```

***P.S.: Drop table first and try again.***

Comment: "Unknown arguments passed to Column: ['sqlite_autoincrement']" and when id2 has autoincrement = False, it still says "NOT NULL constraint failed". Currently my db is sqlite3, but i will soon change it to postgres, maybe it will work there...

Comment: With sqlalchemy 1.1.3, on SQLite, I had to use Column(BIGINT().with_varient(Integer, "SQLite"), primary_key=True). SQLite_autoincrement wasn't recognized but should be automatic for a primary key. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlite-auto-incrementing-behavior